# How to render Razor PartialView with Ajax when link is clicked

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

There is a view like:

```
<a href="#">Render PartialView-1</a>
<a href="#">Render PartialView-2</a>

@foreach(var item in Model.List)
{
    <!-- Some HTML Codes -->

    <div id="partialContainer">
    @foreach(var item2 in item.List)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialView1", item2)
    }
    </div>
}
```

And I have to render PartialView1 or PartialView2 when corresponding link is clicked and content of `partialContainer` should change properly (Default view will be PartialView1 when page is loaded). I checked a lot of questions about this but I have a problem with rendering PartialView inside the `foreach` loop. Because model is change according to outer loop. So I couldn't handle the parameters of AJAX call.

Comment: your partial view isn't rendering? what is the issue?

Comment: What did you mean by "isn't rendering"? I have two partial views and I chose PartialView1 as a default partial view when page is loaded. But I need ajax call to change content of `partialContainer` when corresponding link is clicked.

Comment: I see, you can make ajax calls to controller action to return parital view and load returned html in div on basis of which a tag is clicked.